# Is $x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ irreducible over set of reals?

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

$x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ = ($x^2$ + 1)($x$ + 1)

I know that both are non-units.

So, since it splits into factors, then it is reducible over reals.

Is my theory correct?

Comment: if $x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2+1)(x+1)$, then obviously it's reducible over $\mathbb R$

Comment: Why? Doesn't $i$ belong to complex numbers? Not reals?

Comment: What definition of irreducibility are you using? The usual definition is that it cannot be factored into smaller nonconstant polynomials, and you have shown above that it does factor.

Perhaps you are thinking that it doesn't *split* in the reals, which is correct, but a somewhat different concept. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field)

Comment: Actually, I just started doing this topic so I am a little weaker on the subject. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you know you can enclose entire expressions in dollar signs? `$x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$` becomes a lot prettier than `$x^3$ + $x^2$ + $x$ + 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the interests of having an answer instead of only comments:

@Surb is right. For $p$ to be *irreducible* over $\Bbb R$ means no $q\in\Bbb R[X]$ with $1\le\deg q<\deg p$ satisfies $q|p$; it's nothing to do with which roots of $p$ are elements of $\Bbb R$. See also @PacoAdajar's comparison of reducibility to a different question, that of your polynomial's [splitting field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_field), which is $\Bbb Q[i]$.